# What is the highest precision for decimal data types in Entity Framework 7

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I am struggling with the warning "Warning: the decimal property 'PROPERTY' in entity type 'ENTITY' does not have a specific storage type. This can lead to loss of precision if the values are not within the default precision and scale. Oracle recommends explicitly specifying a column type that can hold all values in 'OnModelCreating' with 'HasColumnType,' specifying precision and scale with 'HasPrecision' or configuring a value converter with 'HasConversion. "

I have come to the conclusion that my decimal type values will need an additional attribute [Precision(18,2)] and here my question slides, I would like to get the highest possible precision, what is it? Is it (18,2)? I am using EF 7 and Oracle Database

```
[Precision(18, 2)]
public decimal? Price { get; set; }
```

Comment: Depends on what database you're using. Oracle?

Comment: Google "oracle entity framework data types", the first hit suggest decimal is mapped to `Number(19,0)`. But I know nothing about oracle, and a scaling of '0' seem weird to me for a decimal data type.

Comment: @PoulBak Yes, I am using Oracle

Comment: Basically, C# numeric data types have a value range that is based on **binary** representation. Like Decimal.MaxValue = 79228162514264337593543950335. In contrast, when you specify an oracle number, you can set the allowed number of **decimal digits**. So, it's impossible to chose an oracle `NUMBER(X, Y)` where the min and max value equals the min and max value of a C# decimal. Without additional check constraints, your oracle field will either allow values that are out of range for C# decimal, or it will be to small for parts of the c# decimal value range.

Comment: So, are you looking for the "highest possible precision" in C# or Oracle?

Comment: Since you property is called `Price` your current setting is probably fine (2 decimal digits) and unless it's 'price of the world', you will probable never get a value with more  than 18 digits.